# Environment variables inside of an environment file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

## Background

I was deploying my docker environment to a production server when I've noticed that the application would not work. For some reason the environment variables were not set correctly inside the containers. It's also important that I define the environment via [environment files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

## The problem

I was able to track the problem down to the point when I realized, that `docker-compose` would not expand the variables defined inside the environment file on my production server while on my development machine it does what I intuitively expect it to do.

## Demo configuration

This simple configuration would work in my development environment only. In production it will yield:

> ERROR: no such image: ${DISTRIBUTIVE}:${TAG}: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

```
# .env
DISTRIBUTIVE=debian
TAG=latest
IMAGE=${DISTRIBUTIVE}:${TAG}

# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.0"
services:
    service:
        image: "${IMAGE}"
```

## Possible causes of the problem

I think that maybe that's a new feature of `docker-compose` (to expand the variables) and maybe it's related to the fact that I've got a fresher install of docker on my development machine.

- Dev

  - docker - 19.03.12-ce
  - compose - 1.27.3
- Prod

  - docker - 19.03.13
  - compose - 1.21.0

## Questions

- Is there any documentation regarding variables inside environment files?
- If that's a new feature then what are version requirements for it?

Comment: That version of compose is rather old. Why isn't it more recent?

Comment: @MichaelHampton well... Apparently, that's the newest version available here on Debian 10... Should probably install it from Docker repos instead.

Comment: I don't think Docker ships packages for docker-compose. I can't find them anyway.